# B85M Pro4 vs B85M-ITX

Tags: motherboard

I'm comparing those two models of ASRock B85M, trying to find which one is the best.

Let's take a tour:
http://www.asrock.com/mb/compare.it.asp?SelectedModel=B85M+Pro4&SelectedModel=B85M-ITX

I'm stucked because I found that Pro4 has more RAM slot (4), with max 32GB; ITX only 2 max 16GB. Pro4 has also more PCI slot. The real different is that ITX got also 1xeSata port. I thought that Pro4 was really better than ITX, but still find ITX $30 more.

What am I missing?

I need to make a simple home server, using Intel Pentium G3258 and Saphire  HD5750. Another question: is better g3460 with lower GPU feature than g3258? I'll use the saphire for graphic.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for $30 extra for ITX is because it is smaller physically. You are paying for higher precision engineering (same stuff needs to fit into a smaller square) also explains less PCI and RAM ports. The ITX board will also in theory use a bit less power.

The ITX board also has a TPM header the other one doesnt.

More info here: 
https://superuser.com/questions/810276/why-very-few-modern-motherboards-are-equipped-with-tpm

Yes the G3460 is going to be better for you if you use the Saphire card.